# Counting Database records that meet criteria and displaying in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5.2

*Using MVC5 EF6 VS2013*

I am relatively new to MVC and Web development in general and am wondering the best way to query the database and count the number of records that meet a criteria out of the total number of records.  In my case I want to count the number of **active vehicles**.

I have used the method I know to display both active and inactive records in a table by querying the database table of vehicles and creating a model of **Active status** and **Counts**

The relevant bits from the Model, Controller and View is below.

**Model**

```
namespace ATAS.Models
{
public class ActiveVehicles
    {
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public int VehicleCount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {


        IQueryable<ActiveVehicles> data = from vehicle in db.Vehicles
                               group vehicle by vehicle.Active into active
                                           select new ActiveVehicles()
                                           {
                                               Active = active.Key,
                                               VehicleCount = active.Count()
                                           };
    return View(data.ToList());

    }
```

**View**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Active
        </th>
        <th>
            Fleet
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Active)
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.VehicleCount
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

**What I want to achieve**

On my view I want to display something like *There are **13** out of **20** vehicles active.*

*What is the best way to achieve this outcome?*

***EDIT - I found one way to achieve it but I am sure it is not best practice.***

It gets me what I want but I am sure it is not efficient.  Any better solutions?

**New Controller**

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        int countALLVehicles = (from row in db.Vehicles
            select row).Count();
        ViewBag.AllVehicles = countALLVehicles;

        int countActiveVehicles = (from row in db.Vehicles
            where row.Active == true
            select row).Count();
        ViewBag.ActiveVehicles = countActiveVehicles;

        var percentActive = (double)countActiveVehicles / (double)countALLVehicles * 100;
        ViewBag.percentActive = percentActive;

        return View();

    }
```

**New View**

```
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <span class="text">Ambulance
          <span class="pull-right">@ViewBag.ActiveVehicles of @ViewBag.AllVehicles</span>
      </span>
      <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar bg-color-blueDark" style="width: @ViewBag.percentActive%;"></div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got curious by your question and wanted to know the result myself.

I believe you can achieve this with a cross join or a better technique but I can't help you so much in the Linq syntax on generating it (sorry for that). I did create an SQL query for it and executed it directly on the context's db. Ensure the columns returned match the names of the properties in your model.

[SQL Fiddle of cross join.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/efdcb/13)

Code for execution and retrieval.

```
         query = @"SELECT COUNT([Status]) As VehicleCount,
                   T2.Active
                   FROM Table1
                   CROSS JOIN
                   (
                     SELECT COUNT([Status]) As Active
                     FROM Table1
                     GROUP BY [Status]
                     HAVING [Status] = 1
                   ) AS T2
                   GROUP BY T2.Active";

       ActiveVehicles data = uow.Context.Database.SqlQuery<ActiveVehicles>(query).FirstOrDefault<ActiveVehicles>();
```

Hopefully you or someone with better knowledge in Linq can turn the query directly into LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an OUTPUT parameter for the count in your stored proc that pulled the data.